Strings are printed like integer with scientific notation in python
a=str(141528231211101319151414.0)
print(a)
# 1.4152823121110133e+23

This string was printed with scientific notation. I do not understand why.
I am using mpmath to deal with arithmetic operations with big numbers. What i want to do is remove ".0" from string to compare, i couldn't find a method for integer division, results are always float in this library. (mpmath)

use int(...) instead of str(). You can convert to a string afterwards but big floats get converted to scientific notation regardless

This badly smells like the XY problem...

int(...) and Decimal() returns number incorrectly

@user409 please read my expanded answer. I think the problem might not be that a precise number is being rounded for printing, it is that the number you see in your editor is already being rounded in memory.

Can you give us a bit more code, including how you import and configure mpmath and create your numbers? Your example only deals with regular floats, not mpmath-floats.

You can avoid scientific notation by using a format specifier, like {:.10f} where 10 in this case is the number of decimal places you want after the comma. The other answer sets this to 0, which essentially means you are rounding to integers. eg: "{:.0f}".format(3.5) # -> 4.
This answer assumes you would want to print "3.5" for 3.5. You can achieve this by defining the decimal format (with a fixed number of decimal places), giving you a result of eg "3.5000" for 3.5. Then, just use simple string-manipulation to drop the trailing zeroes. If no zeroes remain, you can strip the decimal point too.
def fmt(num):
    # show 6 decimal places at maximum
    return "{:.6f}".format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')


print(fmt(3.5)) # 3.5
print(fmt(124)) # 124
print(fmt(141528231211101319151414.0)) # 141528231211101325361152
print(fmt(1e-5)) # 0.00001

You may trip over 141528231211101319151414.0 being printed as 141528231211101325361152. This is not a problem of the printing function but of floating point rounding. Try this:
print(141528231211101319151414.0 == 141528231211101325361152)
# True

Yes. Large numbers in float have less precision than an integer. This is the normal and expected behaviour of floats, be aware of it.

Everything up to this point assumes you turn your mpmath-floats into regular python floats (64bit IEEE-numbers). If you do not convert them first, things change:
You cannot use the mpmath-floats with the fmt-function above, because they don't seem to support format specifiers (you get errors if you try). But the regular printing of the numbers themselves depends on the precision (dps) of your mp-configuration.
import mpmath as mp

mp.mp.dps = 10 # lower than normal precision
a = mp.mpf("141528231211101319151414.0")
b = mp.mpf("141528231211101325361152")
print(a == b) # True
print(a) # 1.415282312e+23
mp.mp.dps = 50 # higher than normal precision
a = mp.mpf("141528231211101319151414.0")
b = mp.mpf("141528231211101325361152")
print(a == b) # False
print(a) # 141528231211101319151414.0

So mpmath already tries to print your number precisely, without scientific notation, if the number is actually saved precisely.

I tested this without downloading mpmath, these are regular floats. Hope it still works, if not, it is probably possible to convert an mpmath-float to a normal python 64-bit-float.

Printing 141528231211101325361152 instead of 141528231211101319151414 doesn't seem optimal...

@nocomment you are right, I didnt catch that. However, that is due to the rounding rules of float. I am adding a warning and checking out if mpmath has something better.

They should show us what they're actually doing and we shouldn't post speculative answers poking around in the dark with something they don't actually have.

@nocomment I kind of agree, my answer got bigger than I anticipated, because the problem is more open than I originally realized.

@jul lowering than normal precision can help, thanks.

@user409 It is unclear to me what you mean. Are you solving your problem by increasing the precision?

As to the "why". Python first reads and interprets the number constant as a float object. That already changes the number to be in the range of the 64bit floating point numbers. The string representation is then the one for such float numbers, due to the size of the number a scientific notation is produced. Printing the string then just prints the string.
This automatic conversion of naked number constants is also the reason that multi-precision numbers should be initialized from strings. This may not be necessary for small integers, but if the number has more than 15 digits, the detour to 64bit floats will lose information/accuracy.
Note that python itself already has a multi-precision integer type. Thus this conversion problem does not occur with many-digits integer constants.

When you convert a large number to a string in Python, it may be represented in scientific notation, especially if it's very large. If you want to print it without scientific notation, you can use string formatting.
a = str(141528231211101319151414.0)
print("{:.0f}".format(float(a)))


Although you'd probably skip str().

note that this will print "4" if a=3.5. I am not sure that is what OP wants.

You are converting string to float per parser, then float to string per str then again string to float via float and again float to string via .format. Is that not a bit much?
